# Qualcomm Hexagon Inline Assembly

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, hexagon-dsp

I am new to QC Hexagon and I need to optimise lots of loops of a C code. I installed the Hexagon tools and had a look at the manual. My general question is:

Do I need to write inline assembly code or can I use the Hexagon intrinsics simply in the C code? Is there anything special needed to optimise the for loop itself, i.e. the loop counter etc.? Or can I simply write the definition of the for-loop and execute Hexagon intrinsics inside?

I inline assembly code is required, where do I find a good manual how to write such code? I only find excerpts of code, but no real manual on how to write it.

Comment: It very much depends on what you're doing, but generally the intrinsics should work. You shouldn't have to drop into inline assembly in order to make use of the HW looping constructs (the compiler should take care of these when possible). In general I think it's a good idea to first see if the compiler does the right thing by itself. (Also, I suggest you find the Hexagon Programmer's Reference Manual for your Hexagon model, for information on assembly syntax and limitations, if that's a direction you're taking.)

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to write inline assembly code or can I use the Hexagon
> intrinsics simply in the C code? Is there anything special needed to
> optimise the for loop itself, i.e. the loop counter etc.? Or can I
> simply write the definition of the for-loop and execute Hexagon
> intrinsics inside?

If you're just starting out, you should probably consider using the intrinsics before jumping into assembly.  Either way, the PRM is a great starting point -- for example, the [v66 PRM](https://developer.qualcomm.com/qfile/67415/80-n2040-42_a_qualcomm_hexagon_v66_programmer_reference_manual.pdf).

You absolutely can use intrinsics inside a C/C++ `for` loop.  The compiler is responsible for bundling the instructions into packets and optimizing the instructions specified by the intrinsics.

Comment: If the compiler does a good job, you could say *instead of* inline asm, not *before*.

Comment: There are some instructions for which intrinsics are not provided, the use cases aren't explicit here.

Comment: Thanks. How can one load and process multiple memory entries at the same time, i.e., unroll a MAC-loop? I don't really understand how to vector-load data and then use it.

Comment: @Dario please post this as a new question, it's not really covered by the scope of this one.